# Will Google Cloud run this type of application?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a python script which run 24 hours on my local system and my script uses different third party libraries that are installed using pip in python
**Libraries**

```
BeautifulSoup
requests
m3u8
```

My python script is recording some live stream videos from a website and is storing on system. How google cloud will help me to run this script 24/hours daily and 7days a week.I am very new to clouds. Please help me i want to host my script on google cloud so i want to make sure that my script will work there same as it is working on local system so my money will not lost .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can. I would recommend familiarizing yourself with this [Quickstart: Deploy a Python Service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) and [What is Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run). When you use Cloud Run, you can provide your own `Docker` image that uses Python, or select from preexisting images.

Once you have a Cloud Run instance running, you can tie it into other Cloud Run instances or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/console-quickstart-1st-gen) which are scalable functions that  use Cloud Run under-the-hood and allow you to easily scale your app. Additionally, these instances spin down to 0 if nobody is using the app which saves costs greatly. This can be modified of course so that the app is always spun-up.

In general I highly recommend looking at Cloud Run but also other services can handle the task such as a [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run 24/7 application on the cloud, whatever the cloud, you must not use solution with timeout (like Cloud Run or Cloud Functions).

You can imagine using App Engine flex, but it won't be my best advice.

The most efficient for me (low maintenance, cost efficient), is to use GKE autopilot. A Kubernetes cluster managed for you, you pay only the CPU/Memory that your workloads use.

You have to containerize your app to do that.